# Dynamically modifying .NET DataSet DataTable

Tags: .net, datatable, dataset, dataadapter

I’ve got a predefined Dataset with DataTables and DataAdapters in my applications.  However, I now want to be able to modify the SP in SQL Server to add fields as needed, and have that reflected in the DataSet’s DataTable dynamically.  This goes from a WebService into XML then goes to the client and gets converted back to the DataSet and DataTable.

I can call the Stored Procedures directly and get a dataset back as a result, but I want to dynimcally update the datatable in master Dataset to match the new results and then pass this back as the XML result from the WebService.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a problem. Just ensure that your SQL Select does not specify the column names to return, i.e. `SELECT * FROM ...` (although such SQL statements are obviously not best practice!)